# Why is GCC inserting seemingly unneeded variables into my assembly file?

Tags: gcc, arm, c-preprocessor

I have an assembly file which can be seen below. It only has a few functions, and once compiled, I only want those functions to be in the binary.

```
#include            <arm.h>

.section            vectors

reset:              ldr pc, =entry

undefined:          b undefined

swi:                b swi

prefetch_abort:     b prefetch_abort

data_abort:         b data_abort

reserved:           b reserved

interrupt_request:  b irq

fiq:                b fiq

irq:

.text

entry:              mov     sp,     #stack_address

                    bl      init

.end
```

But when I compile it, NM reveals this. It has a few superfluous variables in it.

```
00000000 t reset
00000004 t undefined
00000008 t swi
0000000c t prefetch_abort
00000010 t data_abort
00000014 t reserved
00000018 t interrupt_request
0000001c t fiq
00000020 t irq
0000002c T init
00000040 T main
00008024 t entry
00080000 N _stack
a0000000 D __data_start
a0000000 D a
a0000004 D b
a0000008 D __bss_end__
a0000008 D __bss_start
a0000008 D __bss_start__
a0000008 D __end__
a0000008 D _bss_end__
a0000008 D _edata
a0000008 D _end
```

Why is gcc inserting unnecessary variables such as **data_start, __bss_end**, __bss_start, etc.  into my code?

Comment: These variables don't **all** take space.  They just define addresses.  The `-nodefaultlibs` and `-ffreestanding` and maybe `-nostdlib` will get rid of un-needed code/data.

Answer (score 5):

What's happening is GCC is linking the default libraries into the project and including all of their functions. You need to compile with `-nodefaultlibs` to prevent this.

Comment: That worked, but I still got an error saying that the functions that newlib was accessing were undefined. It was fixed by compiling with -nostdlib, however some unneeded variables were still left behind. Do you know how to get rid of those?

Comment: @George - are you passing `-ffreestanding`?

Comment: Passing `-ffreestanding` didn't change the dump of NM.

Answer (score 4):

The linker script defines those so that you can have a .data section or zero the .bss section in the startup code.  Use your own linker script as well as the other answers, nodefault this nostd that, etc.

Comment: So is there any way to get rid of them?

Comment: yes, use your own linker script (where you dont have these variables defined)

Comment: I am using my own linker script.

`SECTIONS {

 . = 0x00000000;

 .text : { * (vectors);  * (.text); }

 .rodata : { * (.rodata); }

 text_end = .;

 . = 0xA4000000;

 .data : AT (text_end) { * (.data); }

 .bss : { * (.bss); }

}`